# DGV CellPainting behaving unexpectedly

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am displaying a list of hours in a DataGridView and would like to shade those hours which fall outside of business hours. I am trying to do this using CellPainting, however I am getting weird results. Could someone please explain what I am doing wrong here?

```
private void dgvItemView_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    switch (_formType)
    {
        case FormType.DayView:
            TimeSpan openTime = iFlow.Properties.Settings.Default.BusinessHourOpen;
            TimeSpan closeTime = iFlow.Properties.Settings.Default.BusinessHourClose;

            DataGridViewCell cell = this.dgvItemView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];

            if (cell.RowIndex < openTime.Hours || cell.RowIndex > closeTime.Hours)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(25, Color.Red)), e.ClipBounds);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

However this code results in a gradient effect, as follows:

[image: Form]

Which I really don't understand. The shading also disappears and re-appears when I scroll up and down, depending on how much I scroll by.

So could someone please explain what I am doing wrong here? I am also going to need to paint partial blocks in case business hours are not on the hour e.g. 08:45 to 17:30, so I can't just change the cell's BackColor to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.ClipBounds` refers to the entire visible part of the `DataGridView`.
What you're essentially doing is painting multiple transparent layers over the entire visible `DataGridView` area, resulting in a gradient effect as you scroll.

You should be using `e.CellBounds` instead.

Another issue, unrelated to your problem, is that you are leaking GDI handles from the `SolidBrush`. `Dispose()` of your `SolidBrush` after painting, or better yet, use a `using` statement as such:

```
using (var sb = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(25, Color.Red)))
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(sb , e.CellBounds);
}
```

*edit:*

You must also set `e.Handled` to `true` after painting, to prevent the system from painting over your work.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellpaintingeventargs.aspx):

> If you manually paint the cell, set the HandledEventArgs.Handled
>   property to true. If you do not set HandledEventArgs.Handled to true,
>   the cell will paint over your customizations.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I'd looked for a cell bounds but obviously not very well. I have changed it to CellBounds and now get no red cells at all, although they occasionally flicker red when scrolling. I have also checked the code is getting called just once, which it is. It is as if another event is subsequently repainting the cells?